# ASNetworkImageNode Cache

Tags: caching, swift

I have a project in which I am adding ASNetworkImageNodes inside an ASCollectionView. What I am stuck with is how to enable caching for the same. I am unable to properly use ASImageCacheProtocol in swift.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use method:

- (instancetype)initWithCache:(nullable id)cache downloader:(id)downloader NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

Or use the default init method, but you need to have the PINCache framework.

Answer (score -2):

try WebASDKImageManager : https://github.com/ide/WebASDKImageManager
It can resolve your problem

Comment: Read the description of WebASDKImageManager  :  This is an implementation of ASImageDownloaderProtocol and ASImageCacheProtocol that is compatible with ASNetworkImageNode